# Error al Desplazar Gridview

Tags: java, android

Soy nuevo en [android](/questions/tagged/android) y estoy desarrollando una aplicación,  en la cual lleno un `gridview` con una consulta a base de datos, mi problema es que el `grid` tiene mas de 40 filas y cuando me desplaza para mostrar las ultimas filas la aplicación se cierra y no me permite mostrar dicha información
muestro aquí el Error:

> 07-26 11:17:14.609 24189-24189/com.example.elprofe.appivonnegroup E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                                  Process: com.example.elprofe.appivonnegroup, PID: 24189                                                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException                                                                                       at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)                                                                                       at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)                                                                                       at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2285)                                                                                       at android.widget.GridView.makeAndAddView(GridView.java:1345)                                                                                       at android.widget.GridView.makeRow(GridView.java:345)                                                                                       at android.widget.GridView.fillDown(GridView.java:287)                                                                                      at android.widget.GridView.fillGap(GridView.java:247)                                                                                      at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5425)                                                                                      at android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:4536)                                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)                                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:543)                                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606)                                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

así es como lleno el grid :

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplegridview, datos2); 
GridView grdOpciones = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.grdOpciones2); 
grdOpciones.setAdapter(adaptador);
```

el Objetivo es solo mostrar la información y poder desplazarse hasta ver la ultima fila, pero solo puedo recorrer 10 filas y me cierra la aplicación

este es el codigo del procedimiento para llenar el grid:

```
iconnect = cn.CONN("sa", "kw1245", "Sis_BD_Inversiones_David", "192.168.0.202:1433");
    ResultSet rs;
    ResultSet rs2;
    try {
        String sql = "SELECT top 15 [Descripcion]\n" +
                "              ,[Precio]\n" +
                "              ,[NombreCliente] \n" +
                "              ,[Fecha]\n" +
                "FROM vwConsultaProductosLocal WHERE Descripcion like('%"+nombre.getText()+"%') and NombreCliente like('%"+ValorBusca.getText()+"%') \n" +
                "order by fecha desc";


        String sql2 = "SELECT count(*) as cont FROM vwConsultaProductosLocal WHERE Descripcion like('%"+nombre.getText()+"%') and NombreCliente like('%"+ValorBusca.getText()+"%')"

        Log.e("E", sql);
        Statement statement = connect.createStatement();
        Statement statement2 = connect.createStatement();
        rs2 = statement2.executeQuery(sql2);
        rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);




        ///contador de Filas
        int filas=0;
        while (rs2.next()) {
            filas= Integer.parseInt(rs2.getString("cont").toString());
        }

        String[][] datos = new String[filas][3];
        String[]datos2 = new String[(filas*4)+4];
        ////Termina contador de Filas
        int i=0;
        datos2[i] = "Descripción";
        i++;
        datos2[i] = "Precio";
        i++;
        datos2[i] = "Cliente";
        i++;
        datos2[i] = "Fecha";
        i++;
        while (rs.next()) {

            datos2[i] = rs.getString("Descripcion").toString();
            i++;
            datos2[i] = rs.getString("Precio").toString();
            i++;
            datos2[i] = rs.getString("NombreCliente").toString();
            i++;
            datos2[i] = rs.getString("Fecha").toString();
            i++;

        }//TERMINA rs-.next

        ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplegridview, datos2);

        GridView  grdOpciones = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.grdOpciones2);;
        grdOpciones.setAdapter(adaptador);

        connect.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ERROR CP", e.getMessage() + "------ENCP");
    }`
```

Comment: Leonel me parece que es un recurso en un layout el que causa el problema, de tu logcat agrega donde muestre "Caused by", creo que lo mejor es agregar tu código.

Comment: Elenasys eso es todo lo que me muestra, no me genera el Caused by, este es el codigo donde lleno el grid,                            ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador =
                    new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplegridview, datos2);

            GridView  grdOpciones = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.grdOpciones2);;
            grdOpciones.setAdapter(adaptador);

Comment: Ok entonces pega el código de tu getView() por favor, me parece que es un elemento de tu listado de objetos que no existe.

Comment: asi es como lleno el grid                                                                              ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador =
         new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplegridview, datos2);

  GridView  grdOpciones =(GridView)findViewById(R.id.grdOpciones2)
            grdOpciones.setAdapter(adaptador)                                          el Objetivo es solo mostrar la informacion y poder desplazarse hasta ver la ultima fila, pero solo puedo recorrer 10 filas y me cierra  la aplocacion

Comment: Ok creo saber que sucede, agrega por favor como inicializas datos2, que contiene datos2?

Comment: voy a pegar todo el metodo que utilizo en la pregunta

Comment: muchas gracias Leonel.

Comment: Gracias  por tu interes en ayudarme Elenasys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para resolver este problema, debes asegurar que los datos que obtengas del ResultSet no sean nulos al introducirlos al array `datos2[i]` :

```
while (rs.next()) {

            datos2[i] = rs.getString("Descripcion").toString();
            i++;
            datos2[i] = rs.getString("Precio").toString();
            i++;
            datos2[i] = rs.getString("NombreCliente").toString();
            i++;
            datos2[i] = rs.getString("Fecha").toString();
            i++;

        }
```

Cuando se tratan de desplegar los datos en la pantalla por medio del adapter, encuentra algún valor null por esa razón puedes visualizar algunas filas pero se cierra al encontrar un valor null.

Comment: tenias razon mi problema estaba en en arreglo, sabes si existe un metodo para editar el tamaño de las columnas, es decir que no sean iguales, sino que dependan del texto mas largo de cada columna, se puede?